# How to get the char data range in PowerPoint by C#/VBA?

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint, office-interop

I have a PowerPoint file and on slide 4 I have a chart. Now, I want to get the chart data range in this slide. But my program is not work correctly.
[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
for (int i = 1; i <= oPP.Slides[4].Shapes.Count; i++)
        if (oPP.Slides[4].Shapes[i].HasChart.ToString() == "msoTrue" && 
            oPP.Slides[4].Shapes[i].Chart.ChartType.ToString() == "xl3DBarClustered")
        MessageBox.Show(oPP.Slides[4].Shapes[i].Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem. Sorry if my English  is not good. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what is not working and what is expected

Comment: It's give the result: =SERIES(Sheet1!$B$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5,1). But when I change the range in Chart data range to A1:D5. It have the same result.

Comment: anyone can help me??